# Multiple Images in one frame Beamer

Tags: beamer, floats, diagrams, itemize

I have to do a presentation for an interview and I want to show in a slide in which there is a list of items after an item a sequence of 3 images that appear one over the previous in a specific position of the page. After I finished the 3rd figure I want that all the 3 pictures will disappear.

this is the code I wrote without the inserting of the images:

```
\section{Academic Background}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Courses of the Master Degree}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Main Courses}
\begin{block}
{\textit{Robotics Control}$\rightarrow$ Prof. Bruno Siciliano}
\end{block}
\begin{block}
{\textit{Nonlinear Control}$\rightarrow$ Prof. Mario Di Bernardo }
\end{block}
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}
    {\textbf{\textit{Robotics Control}}\\Prof. Bruno Siciliano}
    \begin{itemize}
        \tick Industrial Robots
        \pause
        \tick Direct and Inverse Kinematics
        \pause
**I WANT THE THREE PICTURES HERE !!!**
        \tick Direct and Inverse Dynamics
        \pause
        \tick Planning of the EE Trajectory 
        \pause
    \end{itemize}      
    Different robot control techniques:\\
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Centralized and Decentralized Control
        \pause      
        \item Pre-Computed Torque Control       
        \pause      
        \item PD Control with Gravity Compensation 
        \pause      
        \item Force Control
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

Thanks for your help,
Fab.

Comment: And where is the `\tick` command defined?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one possibility using `\only`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bbding}

\newenvironment<>{citemize}
  {\bgroup\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\Checkmark}\begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}\egroup}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}
    {\textbf{\textit{Robotics Control}}\\Prof. Bruno Siciliano}
    \begin{citemize}
        \item Industrial Robots\pause
        \item Direct and Inverse Kinematics\pause
\only<3-5>{
\begin{center}
        \only<3-5>{\par\smallskip\raisebox{-0.5\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-a}}}
        \only<4,5>{\par\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-b}}}
        \only<5>{\par\raisebox{-1.5\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{example-image-c}}}
\end{center}
}
        \item<6-> Direct and Inverse Dynamics
        \item<7-> Planning of the EE Trajectory
    \setcounter{beamerpauses}{7} 
    \end{citemize}\pause   
    Different robot control techniques:\pause
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item Centralized and Decentralized Control
        \item Pre-Computed Torque Control       
        \item PD Control with Gravity Compensation 
        \item Force Control
    \end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The original definition of `\tick`:

```
\newcommand*\tick{\item[\Checkmark]}
```

is not a good one, since `\tick` is not overlay aware (which is desirable and, in fact, it's needed in the present situation). In my code I defined an overlay-aware `citemize` environment that changes the item label to `\Checkmark` and still lets you use the standard `\item` command.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. !!! It's really useful.
But If I want the figures overlapped and not just one after another, how can I do that?
Thanks a Lot,
Fab.
p.s. The \tick command was defined as: \newcommand*\tick{\item[\Checkmark]}

Comment: I did it in this way:
`\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (img1) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{uninalogo.jpg}};
  \pause
  \node (img2)at (img1.south east) {\includegraphics[height=1cm]{uninalogo.jpg}};
  \pause
  \node (img3)at (img2.south east){\includegraphics[height=1cm]{uninalogo.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}`

But the '\pause' command seems not working.

Comment: @minidiable Seeing the code in your comment, I guess I know what you are trying to achieve. Please see my updated answer. Is it something like that what you want?